# Trap doesn't exit the loop

Tags: bash, shell, githooks

I'm trying to do a cleanup using `trap` command. The `safe_cancel` function is being called when I hit a `Ctrl + C` but the script isn't being exited. I have to use `Ctrl + Z` to suspend the script and then `kill`.

The `foo` is another script I have in my PATH which returns an `exit 1` if it receives an invalid argument.

What am I lacking or doing wrong in this script?

```
#!/bin/bash

safe_cancel () {
    echo "Cancelling..."
    # do some cleanup here
    exit 1
}

trap safe_cancel 1

while true; do
    read -p "Choose an option: " someOption < /dev/tty
    foo $someOption
    if [[ $? == 0 ]]
    then
        break
        exit 0
    fi
done
```

**Additional details:**

I'm writing this script for a Git hook. Apparently, git hooks aren't exactly expecting a standard in/out so I have to explicitly use `/dev/tty`

**Edit:**

When using this as part of a git hook, I'm receiving the error 
`read: read error: 0: Input/output error` 
and it's an infinite loop

Comment: If you have an IO error reading from the redirected FD, the clear meaning is that you don't have TTY access from that process. `/dev/tty` only works from processes with a controlling TTY.

Comment: BTW, see [Why is testing "$?" to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36313216/14122)

Comment: If you don't have a controlling TTY, that also would explain why ctrl+c is not delivering a signal (so the script interpreter wouldn't have any way of knowing that you typed it).

Comment: BTW, consider putting an `|| exit` on your `read` command to make the loop no longer infinite.

Answer (score 2):

Signal 1 is SIGHUP, which is raised if the terminal goes away, for example because you were connected from a remote machine and your session was interrupted because the network disconnected. When you press Ctrl+C, this sends SIGINT.

```
trap safe_cancel HUP INT
```

This may or may not be related to the error you get with Git.